# mutliple update in mongodb (MONGOOSE)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I always find my self in such situations when I need to make a couple of update requests based on some conditions..

```
if (some true condition) {
        let recordBeforeUpdate = await this.PatchModel.findOneAndUpdate({ "_id": patchId }, { $inc: { inStockPallets: -1, fullfilledPallets: 1 } }, { returnDocument: "before" });
        debug(recordBeforeUpdate);
        if (another true condition) { //based on the recordBeforeUpdate 
          let patch = await this.PatchModel.updateOne({ "_id": patchId }, { $set: {isFulfilled: true} });
          debug(patch);
        }
      }
```

I'm looking for the best practice here, I've used two requests to the database, and I've used `findOneAndUpdate` at first to be able to get the record when updating instead of getting it by third `findOne` request.

so how should I make this in one request to the database?

Answer (score 0):

The mongoose `findOneAndUpdate` method accepts an aggregation pipeline so you can run a conditional update to specific fields inside an aggregation stage. You will need to use `$add` to increment the value of `inStockPallets` and `fullfilledPallets` instead of `$inc` but this is trivial. As you can see both changes are done in one database operation.

Since you haven't shared your schema I have assumed you have a field named `delivered` that is a `String` and when it's value is `yes` then you want to set `isFulfilled` to `true`, otherwise it will be `false`. Clearly you can modify this to suit your needs:

```js
const patch = await this.PatchModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    { "_id": patchId },
    [ //< Aggregation stage
        {
            $set: {
                isFulfilled: {
                    $cond: [ //< Set the isFulfilled based on the following condition
                        {
                            $eq: [
                                "$delivered", //< The name of the field you want to check
                                "yes" //< The value that you want to check is true
                            ]
                        },
                        true, //< Set isFulfilled to true if {delivered: "yes"}
                        false //< Set isFulfilled to false if {delivered: "anything other than yes"}
                    ]
                },
                inStockPallets: {
                    $add: [ "$inStockPallets", -1 ]
                },
                fullfilledPallets: {
                    $add: [ "$fullfilledPallets", 1 ]
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    { new: true }
);
```